# Nullable column vs Special Default row for referencing from other tables - which design is better?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Need an advice on 2 DB designs

Suppose we have 2 tables `Artefact` and `User`. Artefact has a reference to a user, that created it. But for quite a long time in our legacy system this reference was stored as a string name, so now it's not possible to recover creator for all artefacts (some corresponding records from `User` table are gone). 
So, 2 options are possible:

1. Create a nullable UserId column for `Artefact` table and fill it with null for artefacts which creator is already dropped.
2. Create a special default record 'Non Exsisting User' in `User` table and reference it from `Artefact` table for all records with unknown creator.

At the moment I'm wondering which of the options is better?

Pros of the second approach

1. Easier sql predicates (no endless `isnull()` and `left joins`)
2. More consistent solution - `Artefact` entity always has parent `User` and you can rely on that

Cons of the second approach

1. Violation of Occam's razor and introduction of unnatural and non-existing business object 'Non Exsisting User'
2. Didn't encounter such an approach throughout my career (which is probably not a very good sign, because all great ideas usually have some history of being applied)

So, I would like to know any other pros&cons about 2 abovementioned database design approaches to make a better decision in my case.

Comment: We use option 2 quite from time to time in fact tables of our data warehouse.  However, these default values are often part of a composite primary key so they can't be null.

Answer (score 1):

Re your pros of the second approach:

> 1. Easier sql predicates (no endless `isnull()` and `left joins`)

Unfortunately you still have another endless idiom: user <> 'Non Existing User'. (The only savings is really the word LEFT when joining between Artefact and User.)

> 2. More consistent solution - `Artefact` entity always has parent `User` and you can rely on that

But SQL allows a foreign key from Artefact (user) to User to be checked when non-null.

The straightforward relational design is to have a separate table:

```
ArtefactUser(artefact, user)  
    pk (artefact, user)  
    fk artefact references Artifact not null
    fk (user) references User not null
```

You may be happy with this. Then the straightforward SQL version to save on joins is to have user be a nullable column in Artefact. That's your option 1.

You just have to be aware of idioms in using nulls (because of SQL 3VL complications) to remove them as near the leaves of query expressions as possible.

Re its cons:

There's nothing wrong in principle with having a special value in a column. But in SQL there is no data type support for doing this.

Eg: We wouldn't want 'Non Existing User' to ever be taken as a user name. So it would be nice to have User user be varchar(n) and Artefact user be varchar(n) U {non_existing_user} where non_existing_user is some value/token/enum distinct from any string. And the corresponding constraint to a FK would be `(select user from Artefact where user<>non_existing_user) <= (select user from User)`. The closest one can get in SQL is using nulls. But NULL isn't treated in queries as a normal value. (Nor like anything meaning "not known" or "not applicable".)

Eg: In your message and a comment you consistently misspelled 'Non Existing User'. (Also "artifact".) No typechecking.

The two columns involved really do accept different sets of values. Other than that, if NULL didn't involve 3VL it would just be a value that wasn't in any type but that a column could also hold. That is essentially your option 2. So it's not horrible to do option 2. (User should be constrained to have user <> 'Non Existing User'.)

In other types and for other purposes, there isn't always a value to use specially.

(Don't forget to consider the choice of a separate table.)

Comment: Thx, but I'm still lacking a strong argument against second approach. user <> 'Non Exsisting User' will not happen often, as soon as we need to select and show this  'Non Exsisting User' record as well as others. And extratable will be also redudant, as soon as each artefact has only one creator, so foreign key from artefact table is sufficient imo.

Comment: Well, one argument would be that you have consistently misspelled 'Non Existing User' because, as I explained in the last paragraph, you have no typechecking. (I guess I can edit that paragraph into a con.)

Comment: I feel this is a bad option, but I still can't firmly formulate why :(

Comment: I appended some considerations to my answer. Good luck.